# How can I automatically limit 4 images per row?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi I am new to react and bootstrap coding... it's pretty cool stuff... but I think the bootstrap CSS is just a little confusing...

I am trying to display only 4 images, on a row, for "n" number of images

[image]

This is a component that I would like to reuse to add images to any page.

I can successfully add images, by clicking the 'choose file' button, but they stack vertically.

[image]

I have tried several different "col-md-x" formatting styles, but I just can't quite figure out how to wrap the images.

Additionally, I would like to to stick with the bootstrap "column" / "row" formatting styles of "col-md-1", "col-md-2" (etc)

I have these files that are involved with the component:

FileDropZone.css

```
/* 
this simply hides the "no file chosen" and file name of the input button
*/
input[type='file'] {
color: transparent;
}
```

FileDropZone:

```
import './FileDropZone.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FileDropZoneFeed from './FileDropZoneFeed';

class FileDropZone extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        files: null,
    }

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
}


handleAddFile = (field, file) => {

    //console.log("handleAddFile");

    let temp = this.state[field] || [];
    temp.push(file);
    this.setState({[field]: temp});
}


handleInputChange(event){

    const input = event.target.files[0]

    if (!input) {
        // user has hit the cancel button
        return;
      }        

    let r = new FileReader();
    r.readAsDataURL(input);
    r.onload = (e) =>{

     this.handleAddFile("files", e.target.result);
    } 
}


render() {
    let inputSelector = (

        // simple choose file button
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
        </div>
    );

    let content = null;
    if(this.state.files !== null){
        content = (
            <FileDropZoneFeed files={this.state.files} />
            ); }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {inputSelector}

            {content}
        </div>
        );} 
}
export default FileDropZone;
```

FileDropZoneFeed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import FileDropZoneItem from './FileDropZoneItem';

class FileDropZoneFeed extends Component {
render() {
const { files } = this.props;

return files.map((file, index) => (
  <FileDropZoneItem key={index} id={index} file={file} />
));
  }
    }

FileDropZoneFeed.propTypes = {
  files: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default FileDropZoneFeed;
```

FileDropZoneItem.js

```
import './FileDropZone.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class FileDropZoneItem extends Component {

render() {
const { id, file } = this.props;

return (
  <div>
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <img src={file} width="200" height="200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  ); } 
}

FileDropZoneItem.propTypes = {
id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
file: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FileDropZoneItem);
```

I expect 4 images (or less) to be placed on a row, and if there are more than 4 images, the next 4 will wrap down to the next row (and so on)

What is happening now, is all the images stack vertically.

**Update 1: 18 Jan 2019**

Per patricks suggestion, remove this "" from FileDropZoneItem render, so it just does this:

```
return (
  <div>
      <img src={file} width="200" height="200"/>
  </div>
  ); } 
}
```

This is what I now get:

[image]

**Update 2: 18 Jan 2019**

trying the suggestion of using flex-container and flex-item and this is what I see when I inspect my app.  I have added two "images" (I took out the img object and replaced it with a square), but as you can see the squares are still stacking, but it looks like the flex-item is going all the way across the page?

[image]

**Update 3: 18 Jan 2019**

I used stever's suggestion about going to CSS-tricks and just copied the code from one of their flex grid demos and ta-da... it worked.  I only had to change my div's to ul and ui elements

```
    <ul className="flex-container wrap">
          {content}
    </ul>

    <ul className="flex-item ">
      <img src={file} width="200" height="200"/>
    </ul>
```

here is the result, looks pretty good:

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of information for this problem. Could you please reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but the first wrapper `div` of  `FileDropZoneItem` will probably interfere with the child div which has the `col-md-3` class in your example. Did you put it there on purpose - have you tried to remove it? The `col-md-3` class would tell the div to behave a certain way, but the wrapper div would cause every `FileDropZoneItem` to be its own breaking block. (in case you did not add additional rules for the `div` tag here)

Comment: @rml - this is as minimal, complete and verifiable as I can provide.  Any less and there wouldn't be enough information to see what is happening.  Additionally, I have tried to "reduce" other problems, (in other posts) and then I get "can you add more information"...

Comment: @Patrick Hübl-Neschkudla - I have tried a lot of different combinations... hence why I posted the question here :-)  I am hoping that somebody that has done something similar would be kind enough to post up their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe bootstrap isn't the best approach? Bootstrap can be clunky and verbose.  It strikes me that the flexbox "flexWrap" attribute is made for situations like this.  Setting

```
`flexDirection: "row", 
flexWrap: "wrap"`
```

to a style object, or

```
`flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap
```

in css should work.

Have a look at this [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/).

Comment: I was leaning towards that... but am hesitant to do so just from a maintainability stand point and the fact SO MANY react examples use "map" to "render" an array of items ... any other possible suggestions?  eg: return files.map((file, index) => (
  <FileDropZoneItem key={index} id={index} file={file} />
));

Comment: Maybe bootstrap isn't the best approach?  Have a look at this flexbox approach...  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/

Comment: I don't get why the rows would need the key of the outside iterator?

Comment: Well, you'd be iterating each row, and within each row you'd be iterating each column.  React always want a key for an iterated element, no?

Comment: ah... yes... true

Comment: please put your CSS tricks link as an answer and I will mark it as the answer.  it worked !

Comment: Thank you stever ! Much appreciated !

Comment: @stever please provide the useful code in your answer, not just a link to the code. Otherwise, if the link breaks in the future, your answer will be rendered useless.

Comment: Sorry will do so now.

Comment: Thank you Blundering Philosopher.  I edited it with some context so that if the link breaks, users will still get a sense of how this approach works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2170191/stever  - Was this a good question?  did it outline all of the necessary information required for you to come up with an answer?  If so, can you please up vote it?  thanks